# Não consigo acessar controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Boa tarde, estou tendo uma grande dificuldade para acessar uma api, via jquery  o mesmo sempre retorna erro 400 e as vezes 415 segue exemplo:
-- Jquery--
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
-- api controller --
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
---Classe--
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguem por favor.

Comment: Cole o código e não um print da sua ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa montar uma string com o Json do seu objeto de data, o JQuery.Ajax espera um plain object como atributo para esse parâmetro...

```
function DescontoCasa(){
    var obj = { empresaId : 1 };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://loclhost:44328/api/financeiro/RelDescontoCasa",
        data: obj,
        contentType: 'application/json'

    });
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @Jefferson, Se a postagem foi a solução para o problema, marque para aceitar como resposta. Isso vai tornar tanto a sua pergunta quanto a resposta úteis para outras pessoas que enfrentem o mesmo problema. E se você gostou da solução apresentada, sinalize que ela foi útil com um voto positivo